# Confidence interval with ols and hac

Tags: regression, autocorrelation

I have to build a confidence interval using OLS and one using HAC (heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent). Which of the 2 ignores the auto-correlation between the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about computing a confidence interval using (1) the "standard" variance/covariance estimator,

$\sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}$

and, alternatively, using (2) a HAC estimator such as the Newey-West estimator, whose form is a little baroque, and which I'm not going to attempt to write down.

Under the assumptions of the classical linear regression model, the "standard" estimator is a consistent estimator of $Var(\hat{\beta})$, but if the errors are heteroskedastic or serially correlated, it is inconsistent.  Meanwhile, if the errors are heteroskedastic and serially correlated, a HAC estimator is consistent--that's what "HAC" means.  Obviously, then, the "standard" estimator, presumably what you call the "OLS" estimator, is the one that "ignores" the auto-correlation between the errors.